# width parameter as variable in rollapply

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(width = c(1,2,2,4), values = c(10,11,13,20))
```

I want to use rollapply to compound the 'values' column, but I want to use a variable width for each row, getting the width from the appropriate row in the 'width' column.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to pass the width parameter as a variable from the 'width' column.

I have a solution using dplyr's mutate, but it's clunky and very slow. Below is my current code, with a static '3' in place of the value I'd like to sub in:

```
rollapply(df[ , values_column], width = 3, function(x) rolling_compounder(x),
                                align = "right", fill = NA, partial = FALSE, by.column = FALSE)
```

EDIT:

Using decimal values:
0.1,
0.11,
0.13,
0.2

And the same widths as above, I would expect the compounded results to be:

0.1,
0.221,
0.254,
0.656

Comment: Expected output? (Love your name) :)

Comment: Thanks. Love yours too. Added the expectation in the question.

Comment: What about `rollapplyr(df$values, width = df$width, sum)`?

Comment: Thanks Jaap. That works! Unfortunately, I'm passing the width column name as a variable too. Sorry, should have mentioned this before. So when I use the syntax width = df[, mycol_name_variable] it doesn't work. Any ideas please?

Comment: No worries, Japp. I figured it out, I rename the column to something static before running the rollapply function. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: If you want to apply it to more than one column, you could do: `lapply(df[2:3], function(x) rollapplyr(x, width = df$w, sum))`